# How to add numbers in mysql database rows?

Tags: c#, mysql, sum, rows

I have a list of price numbers in my MySql datbase rows. I am new to database and so far I already tried `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE` command in MySql, my program is doing well until I encountered this situation where I have to add the price numbers in my database.

I already research this on the web and most of them are in php, .net, sql form so far I cant find C# programming language. I found this php code but I have less experience in php programming language and besides my program is not in php. Anyway, I use Windows Form C#.

php code from :[How do I add up all values of rows in a table?](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/138937/how-do-i-add-up-all-values-of-rows-in-a-table)

```
$query="Select points from members2";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $total=0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $total=$total + $row['points'];
    }
    echo "Total is:" . $total;
```

**EDIT**

Hi Thank you for all your help I get the right output.

```
    string conn = "server=localhost;user=root;password='';database=cashieringdb;";
    MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(conn);
    string sql = "select sum(price) from sales";
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, myconn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    txtSum.Text = dt.Rows[0][0] + "";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this directly from the database, and not worry about PHP or C#. Following query will return the sum of points.

```
    $query="Select sum(points) from members2";
```